# How to get OCI lib to work on red hat machine with R Oracle?

Tags: oracle, r, redhat, oracle-call-interface, rstudio-server

I need to get OCI lib working on my rhel 6.3 machine and I am experiencing some trouble with OCI headers files that can't be found. I have installed (using yum install)

oracle-instantclient11.2-basic-11.2.0.3.0-1.x86_64.rpm

because [this official page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html) it's all I need to run OCI. To test the whole thing in general  I've installed sqplus64, which worked after I set `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib`. Unfortunately the headers files couldn't be found after setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Actually I am not surprised because there is no `include` directory in any of these oracle paths.

So the question is: Where do I get these missing header files from? Are they actually already there and I just can find them?

Btw: I am doing this whole exercise because I want to use ROracle on my R Studio server and this R package depends on the OCI library. Once I am back in R territory the road gets much less bumpier for me.

EDIT: [this documentation](http://switch.dl.sourceforge.net/project/orclib/OCILIB%20Guides/ocilib-3.5.0-user-guide.pdf) helped me a little further. However, I guess I found some header files now in: "/usr/include/oracle/11.2/client64". **But which variable do I have to set to this location?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ladies and gentlemen, the solution is:

```
$ ./configure --with-oracle-headers-path=/usr/include/oracle/11.2/client64/ --with-oracle-lib-path=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/

$ make
$ make install
```

At least this compiles without error. now let's turn to the R package itself:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$ R CMD INSTALL ROracle_1.1-7.tar.gz
```

Details can be found [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROracle/INSTALL).

Comment: Could you specify in which folder you are when you run `./configure ...`?

Comment: I am sorry. Migrated to postgres in the meantime. That post's 4 years old and that server is not operational any more.

Comment: The ./configure is actually in the Roracle package. you can pass the arguments like this  $ R CMD INSTALL --configure-args='--with-oracle-headers-path=/usr/include/oracle/11.2/client64/ --with-oracle-lib-path=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/

Answer (score 3):

1. Download the `oracle-instantclient` and `oracle-instantclient-devel` `rpm`s on [Oracle Instant Client website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html)
2. Install them using yum with `--nogpgcheck` (thanks to [this answer](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/31116/how-do-i-install-unsigned-packages-using-yum/?answer=31119#post-id-31119)):

```bash
yum install --nogpgcheck oracle-instantclient12.1-basic-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm oracle-instantclient12.1-devel-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

3. Now install ROracle by defining `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `OCI_LIB` and `OCI_INC` environment variables (like said in [the doc](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROracle/INSTALL)):

```bash
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH OCI_LIB=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib OCI_INC=/usr/include/oracle/12.1/client64 R -e 'install.packages("ROracle", repos="http://cloud.r-project.org");'
```